# cakephp comma in numeric value not considered valid

Tags: php, cakephp

Hey guys, is there a way to tell cake that values like `2,50` (instead of `2.50`) are valid numeric values?

Thanks, EL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably it's better to create a custom validation rule for this.